# Flask: how to send values by get method in temples?

Tags: python, input, flask

I have a html code such as:

```
<form action="/labeling?id={{id}}" method="get" target="hiddenFrame">
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="x" onchange="this.form.submit()"> X<br>  
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="y" onchange="this.form.submit()"> y<br>
</form>
```

and the python code that gets the id of the element:

@app.route('/labeling', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def labeling():

```
    value = request.form['options']
    d_id = request.form['id']
```

but it does not sent the values of id in the GET request? why?

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` param is not form param, try:

```
d_id = request.args['id']
```

or better use `id` as method param:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('labeling', id=id) }}" method="POST" target="hiddenFrame">
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="x" onchange="this.form.submit()"> X<br>  
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="y" onchange="this.form.submit()"> y<br>
</form>

@app.route('/labeling/<int:d_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def labeling(d_id):
    value = request.form['options']
```